# problem with size of the data in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, knn

I want to apply Kmeans to Whole Sale Customers Data available at:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wholesale+customers

So far my code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('Wholesale customers data.csv')
cont_features = ['Fresh', 'Milk', 'Grocery', 'Frozen', 'Detergents_Paper', 'Delicassen']
dataS=data[cont_features]
mms = MinMaxScaler()
mms.fit(dataS)
data_norm = mms.transform(dataS)
dataNorm=pd.DataFrame(data_norm,columns=cont_features)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5).fit(data)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.predict(data)
data=data.iloc[:,[3,4]].values #only to select two features for visualizing the scatter plot
plt.scatter(data[labels==0, 0], data[labels==0, 1], s=10, c='red', label ='Cluster 1')
plt.scatter(data[labels==1, 0], data[labels==1, 1], s=10, c='blue', label ='Cluster 2')
plt.scatter(data[labels==2, 0], data[labels==2, 1], s=10, c='green', label ='Cluster 3')
plt.scatter(data[labels==3, 0], data[labels==3, 1], s=10, c='cyan', label ='Cluster 4')
plt.scatter(data[labels==4, 0], data[labels==3, 1], s=10, c='cyan', label ='Cluster 5')
    
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], s=10, c='yellow', label = 'Centroids')
plt.title('Clusters')
plt.xlabel('Frozen')
plt.ylabel('Detergent')
plt.show()
```

The problem is when I want to run my code the error that appear is the following:

```
x and y must be the same size
```

and my plot is something like this:

[image]

I am not able to find the mistake. Any help?

Comment: i suggest you to draw the points in 3D for better visualization

Comment: thanks @ombk could you give some hints about it?

Comment: it is very easy. check matplotlib 3D plots.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.scatter(data[labels==4, 0], data[labels==4, 1], s=10, c='cyan', label ='Cluster 5')` Here it was a 3 in the labels part.

Your plot

[image]

```
plt.scatter(data[labels==3, 0], data[labels==4, 1], s=10, c='cyan', label ='Cluster 4')
plt.scatter(data[labels==4, 0], data[labels==3, 1], s=10, c='cyan', label ='Cluster 5')
# also here you are using same colors

plt.legend() # also you forgot that
```